# How to store 2 values

Tags: java

I have to complete this code. I have to find a way to store 2 values and work with them. The program count the number of votes for each candidate and the candidate who has the most votes is the winner. Which tool can allow me to do that?

```
public class vote {

    public vote(String[] candidates) {

    }

    public void votefor(String candidate) {

    }

    public int getnb(String candidate) {

    }

    public String winner() {

    }
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] election = {"candidate1", "candidate2"};
        vote v = new vote(election);
        v.votefor("candidate1");
        v.votefor("candidate2");
        v.votefor("candidate1");
        System.out.println("the winner is "+ v.winner());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code should not compile.

Comment: @PM77-1 Because of lack of returns? They are not saying it will. It looks like a template, designed to be fleshed out. Hence "I don't know where to start".

Comment: You might want to try using a `HashMap<String, Integer>` to map candidate names to the number of votes they have. Or keep a second array of the votes of each candidate in the same order as the candidate names, e.g. the first element stores the votes for candidate 1, the second for candidate 2, and so on.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you use a `HashMap<String, Integer>` to store pairs `candidate/nbVotes`

- at initialization, put every candidates with a score of 0
- when `votefor` increment the candidate by 1
- to get the winner get the one with max score

```
class Vote {

    private HashMap<String, Integer> votes;

    public Vote(String[] candidates) {
        votes = new HashMap<>();
        for (String candidate : candidates) {
            votes.put(candidate, 0);
        }
    }

    public void votefor(String candidate) {
        votes.merge(candidate, 1, Integer::sum);
    }

    public int getnb(String candidate) {
        return votes.get(candidate);
    }

    public String winner() {
        return votes.entrySet().stream().max(Entry.comparingByValue()).map(Entry::getKey).orElse(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] election = {"candidate1", "candidate2"};
        Vote v = new Vote(election);
        v.votefor("candidate1");
        v.votefor("candidate2");
        v.votefor("candidate1");
        System.out.println(v.votes); // {candidate2=1, candidate1=2}
        System.out.println("the winner is " + v.winner()); // the winner is candidate1
    }
}
```